# What is the difference between CommandLineTools, MacosSDK and XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

My main confusion comes from these products seem to each have their own release versions and sometimes, these versions get mixed up and thus, making it very hard to know which version of build tools you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is Apple's app for making apps for Apple's platforms: macOS, iOS, tvOS, and watchOS. Each version of Xcode ships with a version of the SDK for Apple's platforms, including macOS. The site [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com) shows the SDKs that ship with each version of Xcode.

The Command Line Tools package is for people who want access to compilers and other developer tools but don't need Xcode. If you have Xcode installed, you don't need to install the Command Line Tools package because it's part of the Xcode installation.

I'm not sure what is confusing you. I looked at Apple's downloads site, and each version of Xcode has a corresponding Command Line Tools package. You may want to edit your question and add more details as to what's confusing you.

Comment: So is SDK same as Command Line Tools?

Comment: No, the SDK is not the same as the Command Line Tools. The Command Line Tools package does not contain any Apple platform SDKs, such as the macOS SDK.